Eliminate variables from a large system of equations
I have a large system of equations $Ax=0$. For context, the equations are invariants of some model. $A$ is sparse and typically has more columns than rows ($m < n$). The $x$ vector can be divided into variables $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ that I want to eliminate - I only care about the equations expressed in terms of $x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n$ (that constitute about 1% of the $x$ variables). I do this by reducing $A$ to row echelon form and picking up for further processing only the equations that have 0s as the $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ coefficients.
That works great with my hand-rolled elimination, but as my problems are getting bigger (100k+ variables) I am looking for an optimized library that can do it for me. I played with LU factorization from UMFPACK and SuperLU ($A$ is very sparse). I found that those methods use column permutation to minimize the fill-in of $L$ and $U$. This is where my problem starts - I don't want to mix the variables that are meant to be eliminated with the ones that are not by permutating the columns. What can I do about it?

I can disable column permutation and risk high fill-in and reduced performance.
I can do column permutation of the first $k$ columns and the remaining columns separately, and provide such permutation to the factorization routine. Not sure if it makes sense.
I can do the LU factorization of $A'$ which consists of the first $k$ columns of $A$ and then use $L$ to perform row operations on the remaining columns. Can it be done efficiently?

This is my first venture into linear algebra, so let me know if I've missed something obvious.
Edit:
For some additional context, I'm not really looking for solutions to the equations, but rather to reduce the number of equations. As mentioned, These equations are invariants of some model. For example, consider data traveling through a network. One invariant could be that if I put $x_{in}$ amount of data on one side of the link, then the amount at the output ($x_{out}$) is the same ($x_{in} - x_{out} = 0$). Here, $x_{in}$ and $x_{out}$ are unbounded. There are some variables however, that reflect design choices and they are bounded (e.g. buffer size). I want to eliminate all unbounded variables, and keep the invariants expressed in terms of the bounded ones. It will allow me to inspect and prove some properties of the network that depend on the selection of bounded variables.

Have you thought about taking $A$ to be a 2x2 block matrix and working on this block structure if you don't want to mix variables?

Maybe I misunderstood what you mean, but can't you just write $0= Ax = A_1 y +A_2 z$ and then $A_1 y = -A_2 z$, where $y$ is made up of $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ and $z$ is made up of $x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n$. Also you can try looking into iterative methods such as Bi-CGStab.

@WolfgangBangerth - I have not, and it looks like it will address my issue. Thank you!

@lightxbulb - I added more context at the end of my post to clarify what I'm doing.

The additional context didn't help me to understand what you want to do mathematically. It still seems like you just want to do $A_1 y = -A_2z$, since you mentioned you want to "eliminate" some variables. On the other hand you also say you want to reduce the number of equations, so I am not sure which it is. Do you have an overdetermined or underdetermined system of equations?
